# Как получить значение из Gridview?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Есть форма с `GridView` и колонки GridView: Состояние, ИИН,ID итд 
**Код** к примеру:

```
protected void PolicyGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
 long? did = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);
 OneCGateTableAdapters.vw_DealListTableAdapter ta = new OneCGateTableAdapters.vw_DealListTableAdapter();
 OneCGate.vw_DealListDataTable dt = ta.GetDataByID(did);
 OneCGate.vw_DealListRow dr = dt[0];
}
```

Беру ID сделки с помощью `e.CommandArgument`. И метод возвращает ID
Но, проблема в том что когда кликаю след страницу `Gridview`(например 3 страница) он воспринимает это как `ID`(did = 3)
Вопрос: как можно выбрать ID в моем случаи чтобы передать в процедуру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    protected void PolicyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (GridViewRow gr in PolicyGridView.Rows)
       {
         long? did = Convert.ToInt64(PolicyGridView.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
       }
    }
```